# How to replicate an exchange option?

Tags: option-pricing

- The exchange option has payoff $\text{max}\Big(S_{1}(T)-S_{2}(T),0\Big)$.
- Dynamic quantities of **what instruments** should I have to replicate it?

Comment: You only need to trade into $S_1$ and $S_2$. You do _not_ need to trade into a risk-free bond. See Magrabe (1978): https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1978.tb03397.x    The special case is if $S_2$ is constant and you have a vanilla call. The price process of $S_2$ is then kind of a risk-free bond again in which you can trade alongside $S_1$.